# What is this kind of timer called?

Tags: electrical, lighting

Years ago I worked at a farm that had an outside light on an adjustable timer. You turned a dial to set the desired period required for the light to remain on. On leaving the building the switch was pressed and the light came on and remained on for 30 seconds to 30 minutes, as set. I would like to install one as there is too much wildlife for a motion sensor activated light.

Comment: Not sure that this is a shop for me.  More of a product identification.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably looking for either a [spring-wound timer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Intermatic-20-Amp-12-Hour-Spring-Wound-In-Wall-Timer-White-SW12HWK/205478810):

[image: spring-wound timer]

or a (digital) [countdown timer](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Intermatic-15-Amp-60-Minute-Countdown-In-Wall-Timer-White-EC210WK/205478813):

[image: countdown timer]

As @Harper mentioned, you can get them in various time ranges.

---

Products shown are not an endorsement or recommendation, just examples

Comment: They make them in any timeframe you want, from 5 minutes full sweep up to I think I've seen 48 hours?

Comment: There are also pneumatic timers common in some parts of Europe, where they're used for communal areas of shared buildings.