# Can I switch my washer between two power sources? Double throw switch?

Tags: switch

What switch can I use to connect my washer to my electricity and my tenants electricity so that we can switch between the two power sources without having to unplug and plug the machine multiple times?I installed a double throw switch for the dryer and it works perfectly. I can switch between my electricity and my tenants easily.

Comment: What makes you think the washer is different than the dryer?  You said you did the dryer already...

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? As in, what is the setup? I'm assuming there are 2 electrical meters, but not why or how they cross paths in a manner allowing you to switch between them. I'd like to understand fully b/c there may be safety issues here & that goes for swapping plugs as well.

Comment: JPhi1618 - The dryer is connected to a 30 amp line and the washer to a 15 amp line. The double throw switch for the dryer is about 12"x10". I just want a small toggle switch for the 15 amp line but I cant find one.

Comment: Iceberg86300 14 - I want to be able to switch between my electricity and my tenants. There are two outlets, one from their line and one from mine. I don't want to have to switch plugs everytime.

Comment: Is each outlet on a dedicated circuit? IE, one breaker & one plug, nothing else? If so you can accomplish this relatively easily & safely through the use of a changeover switch, but I believe it is still against code. (Commen areas are supposed to get their own service) https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/106758/110820

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to split electricity consumption of an appliance between apartments?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106758/is-it-possible-to-split-electricity-consumption-of-an-appliance-between-apartmen)

Comment: @Iceberg86300 That's for Europe; OP has a harder time of it since OP's dryer is split-phase and must switch 3 conductors.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica Yes, but it's still correct & the answer makes a note of the difference. As you note, in this case it simply requires a 3PDT switch. Which should be of the On-off-on variety if going purely mechanical.

Comment: where is it allowable for a landlord who is clearly not a licenced electrician to do electrical work for his tennant?

Answer (score 3):

### Move the double-pole switch to the washer.

A double-pole switch is just right.   You will switch hot and neutral.  You've already got one for the dryer; move it to the washer.

Switching neutral is essential when the outlets are fed from different **circuits**.  And these are served from different **services**, making it far more critical.

### Get a [3-pole switch](https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-30-Amp-240-Volt-Non-Fused-Indoor-General-Duty-Double-Throw-Safety-Switch-TC35321/202978650?MERCH=REC-_-pipsem-_-302352585-_-202978650-_-N) for the dryer.

The huge problem with electric dryers is that third wire *is not ground. **It is neutral.***  It is an active conductor that handles normal current for all the 120V loads in the dryer - basically every internal device except the heater.  **You must switch neutral**.  You have connected the two service panel's neutrals back to back, which means neutral from either panel has two choices of path -- back through the service entrance, or via the dryer connection to the other tenant's panel.  This can cause all manner of problems, and is certainly the most likely way I can think of to set an apartment on fire.

(or you've connected neutral to only one service, but that has a whole 'nother way to set the house on fire).

[image]

**Neutrals do not have circuit breakers.**  The safety of the neutral wire depends absolutely on the concept that it only returns current from *its* circuit.  As soon as you criss-cross neutrals between circuits, you can overload that neutral. There is a variety of ways that could fail deadly.  Including some that could electrify the chassis of the dryer, because of that obsolete, unsafe 3-prong connection!

Things get *even more* serious when criss-crossing neutrals on two *services*, because now the criss-crossing neutral wire could carry *all the current for the entire service*. That'll start a fire for sure.

It is all right to criss-cross safety ground wires; in fact if you use metal conduit for your wiring method, it's inevitable. I have a building with 4 separate services all sharing the same metal pipes on a metal building, and thus, same safety ground. **But the important thing is that a 3-wire dryer connection has no ground; that wire is neutral**.

Lastly, I very strongly urge you to convert to a 4-wire connection to the dryer, including removing the (technically legal) neutral-ground bootleg strap. Because this type of switching adds a risk of a problem with the neutral (gee, you think? :) and on a 3-wire connection, that causes the chassis of the dryer to become electrified!

### Rule of thumb: Don't do anything a GFCI would have a problem with

If you use a wiring technique that would trip a GFCI breaker, particularly sharing neutral, then don't do that. It was already against Code, but the GFCI keeps you honest :)

NEC 2014 already requires GFCI in the laundry room for 120V outlets e.g. washer.  I advise using GFCI protection *before* the transfer switch, so that everything associated with the switch is protected by GFCI.  That means a GFCI breaker, or a GFCI recep that feeds the transfer switch from its LOAD terminals.

NEC 2020 will require GFCI for the dryer *as well*, and the safest (and most affordable, actually) way to do that is before the transfer switch, so again, the transfer switch is in the zone of protection.  That way any screw-ups with the transfer switch are GFCI protected.

I know 90% of this  has been a "lecture", but I gotta give you more lecture.

### In fact, actually do fit GFCIs... *for liability*.

**Here is where GFCI can save your bacon**.  Make sure that both transfer switches are served by GFCIs **upstream of the transfer switch** e.g. at the breaker - a GFCI switched by the switch is of no help.  However, for that to work, you MUST also convert the dryer to a 4-wire connection, and remove the neutral-ground jumper in the dryer, and also remove any other bootlegged grounds in this area (because those break GFCI protection).  If GFCIs are protecting, you're far better off with no ground than a bootlegged ground.  Neutral and ground must be totally separate for the GFCIs to protect.  Once the GFCIs are installed, it's less important that things *actually be grounded*, although retrofitting ground would be "belt and suspenders" and I would do it for liability reasons.

At this point, you've **done your part** to prevent an electrical shock, and one won't happen.  And if one does anyway:  the investigators will make a  "landlord made full and fair effort, no negligence here, don't charge with manslaughter" recommendation to the DA.  Now you're down to civil fines for violating the *procedural* stuff about permits and electricians.

**All work in a rental unit must be done by a licensed electrician**. That is state law in pretty much every state, and it's to prevent landlords doing their own "hack jobs". You can only do your own work in owner-occupied units.

**Any work of this complexity requires a permit** - precisely so the town inspector can keep an eye on the setup to make sure it is done correctly.

So you've already crossed the line on those; your only defense is doing the work well.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica why not use a 3P for the washer??

Comment: @Iceberg86300 Because North American washers are 120V hot+neutral+ground.  It's not imperative to switch ground, since current does not move on it except in fault conditions.  Neutral, however, is a normal current path.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica doesn't the dryer share the same spec? (Actually, I didn't see anything about it being gas vs electric.)

Comment: @Iceberg86300 if it was gas, switching the primary energy source would be a *whole different kettle of fish*.

Comment: Harper, I am not criss-crossing neutrals, there are only 3 wires coming from the lines and the load and one of them is the ground so why would i need 3 poles?

Comment: @Thomas On a 3-wire dryer, that third wire is not ground. **It is neutral**.  Common misconception. That's why 4-wire connections improve safety, the *fourth* wire is ground.  This is an electric dryer, yes?

Comment: yes an electric dryer

Comment: @Thomas yes, electric dryers take neutral. The 3-wire connection is groundless, but the hack-job of attaching dryer chassis to neutral was "authorized" by NEC until the 1990s due to appliance industry lobbying.  You can see that would play very badly/dangerously with any unusual setup, right?  Hence my urgency to converting it to 4-wire.

Comment: OK, thanks Harper. I see my mistake now, I will get a 3 pole switch for the dryer and use the 2 pole for the washer. I just wish they werent so big. Cant I use a toggle switch instead of a big box?

Comment: @Thomas I know what  you mean.  Yeah, ***if*** you can find a 3-pole double-throw toggle (30A of course) with a UL listing (RU rated components won't cut it).  I've never found little switches like that, not least, because they have 9 terminals and those just won't fit on a standard 1-gang toggle...  They certainly make DPDT 15A switches in 1-gang form factor, so you can at least downsize **the washer**... I saw EdBeal's link, but I would shop more, I could swear I've seen them cheaper than $65.

Comment: Harper - I bought the triple pole double throw switch for the dryer, it's bigger than my electrical panel! It's 15 inches long. I don't understand why they have to make them so big? It looks ridiculous, but Im gonna use it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the washer can be toggled. To do it properly you would need a double pole double throw switch. You need to switch both the hot and neutral from your supply and the tenants to the washer. The common to the washer and each feed on the other contacts.  See Leviton 1286-w 20 amp 120/277v toggle don’t ac switch (the laundry circuit should be a 20a 120v by current code but this switch will work.

Added to clarify how to wire the double pole double throw switch works. 
The connection to the washer is the Common terminal sometimes the center but usually the black one. It may be stamped . one side of the switch gets the black and the other side the white. Then you have 4 terminals left 2 on each side. The black wires or hot all go on the same side of the switch. Whites on the other. The tenant hot and neutral on 1 end and your hot and neutral on the other set , your wires hot and neutral need to stay at the same position end or middle depending on the switch and the tenants need to stay together. The connections need to be made in a box a old work 2 gang box with a mud ring for a switch and outlet will work. In 1 position the power will come from the tenant the other position from yours.

Comment: I bought the Leviton 1282 15 amp . Will this switch work for my purposes?

Comment: I can only find examples of two loads and one line instead of two lines and one load as in my situation. How is it wired?

Comment: check this answer. https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/106758/110820

Comment: Thanks for the help Ed, I tried my Leviton 1282 . I connected my line to one end, the black wire to the black screw and white to the opposite side. When i switched the toggle to that end none of the other screws became hot. When i toggled it to the other end it blew the breaker, so ... I guess Im gonna give up on this idea.

Comment: Don’t give up , on toggles it is usually the center set of contacts that will go to the washer, I would check with an ohm meter , I just don’t have that model of switch. Normally with toggle switches the center contact is connected to the side away from the toggle. So if you connect the washing machine to the center terminals black wires all 3 are on 1 side and white all 3 on the other side  even if wired wrong it should not trip the breaker.  Each side of that switch is a separate switch. The normal pole that toggles from 1 terminal to the other is black or common but could be center